# Can we combine two non-terminals and use this as one non-terminal in CFG?

Tags: computability, context-free

Let's consider this CFG-

```
S->AB [Here, **S** is the starting variable]
A->C
CB->Cb
C->a
```

Now, the question is- Check if **ab** is a valid string for the given string or not?

I thought an answer. And that is-

```
S->AB
 ->CB [A->C]
 ->Cb [CB->Cb]
 ->ab [C->a]
```

My question is, **Can we generate string ab from this CFG in this way?**

Comment: The grammar that you included is _not_ a context-free grammar. The left side of the production rules of a context-free grammar must consist of exactly one non-terminal, but the rule $CB \to CB$ has two non-terminals on the left side. (This is why it's "context free" – the context of a non-terminal does not affect its expansions)

Comment: @CurtisF what it should be?